# In flutter with material 3 enabled, how do I change the color of CupertinoDialogAction text globally?

Tags: flutter, material-design

In a flutter app I have a `ThemeData()` applied to the Material app. Since setting `useMaterial3: true`, some colors across the app have changed. Namely, the Text color for `CupertinoDialogAction` in `CupertinoAlertDialog` has turned purple (`0xFFD0BCFF`).

I don't want to set the color manually for all dialogs across the app. How do I set the default color for the dialog action text? I want to keep using material 3 and not disable it.

In the theme I have tried to set `colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue` but there is no change. I just can't seem to get rid of the ugly purple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the source code of `CupertinoDialogAction`, the text color is computed by:

```dart
color: CupertinoDynamicColor.resolve(
  isDestructiveAction ? CupertinoColors.systemRed : CupertinoTheme.of(context).primaryColor,
  context,
),
```

To change the `CupertinoTheme`'s `primaryColor` when using `MaterialApp`, you could either change the `ThemeData.colorScheme.primary` since the `CupertinoTheme` is derived from the MaterialTheme (check out [MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData-class.html)).

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
  colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
    primary: Colors.blue,
  ),
  useMaterial3: true,
),
```

or

if you want to decouple the Cupertino styling from Material theme, you could provide a `CupertinoThemeData` to the [`ThemeData.cupertinoOverrideTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/cupertinoOverrideTheme.html).

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
  cupertinoOverrideTheme: const CupertinoThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
  useMaterial3: true,
),
```

Comment: This is correct. I actually tried this but it wasn't working because I had some other thing getting in the way. Doh!